# Testing Socket Program

Tags: java, sockets

So I wrote a simple Socket program that send message from Client to Server program and wanted to know what is the proper procedure to go about testing this?  Both my Client and Server machines are running on Ubuntu 12.04 and I'm remote connecting to both of them.

For my Client code when I instantiate the client socket (testSocket) do I use its IP Address and Port number or Servers IP Address and Port number?

Here is the Code for Client:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException 
{
    Socket testSocket = null;
    DataOutputStream os = null;
    DataInputStream is = null;

    try
    {
        testSocket = new Socket("192.168.0.104", 5932);
        os = new DataOutputStream(testSocket.getOutputStream());
        is = new DataInputStream(testSocket.getInputStream());
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException e)
    {
        System.err.println("Couldn't find Host");
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O connection");
    }

    if (testSocket != null && os != null && is != null)
    {
        try
        {
            os.writeBytes("Hello Server!\n");

            os.close();
            is.close();
            testSocket.close();

        }

        catch (UnknownHostException e)
        {
            System.err.println("Host not found");
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.err.println("I/O Error");
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the code for Server:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String line = new String() ;


    try
    {
       ServerSocket echoServer = new ServerSocket(5932);

       Socket clientSocket = echoServer.accept();

      DataInputStream  is = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
      PrintStream os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

           while (true) 
           {
             line = is.readLine();
             os.println(line); 
           }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

I'm new to Sockets and not sure what I'm supposed be seeing.  I compiled both programs in terminal fine but not sure which one should I be running first or do they need to be started simultaneously?

Thanks

Comment: You should start the server first, so the client has something to connect to. In the client, you specify the IP address of the server and the port it is listening on.

Comment: And for the ServerSocket I use that same port number?

Comment: Yes. Have you not tried this? If you are seeing an error, please post it.

Comment: When I start the Server it returns with "Address already in use"

Comment: This issue is seen when sockets are closed in a particular order. You'll find the address is available after a period of time (usually about two minutes). Google "TCP TIME_WAIT" to see an explanation of why this happens.

Comment: I just changed the port number to something else and when I run the Server it executes and looks like its waiting, but when I run Client I get "Couldn't get I/O connection".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server is running in a infinite loop. Avoid that.
You have to restart your computer.

```
while (true) 
           {
             line = is.readLine();
             os.println(line); 
           }
```

try

```
while (!line.equals("Hello Server!")) 
           {
             line = is.readLine();
             os.println(line); 
           }
```

Run the server first. echoServer.accept(); waits for a connection. When it gets the first connection,

Comment: *You have to restart your computer* ... really?

Comment: That seemed to work, but isn't os.println(line); supposed to return the "Hello Server!" message?

Comment: The client is done by the time. So os.printline(line) will not do anything. After writing the bytes in client you can addd te same code in client to wait for "Hello server" message.

Comment: I've just added a simple println message to test it out after the os.println(line) and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/ this is a short java tutorial on how to work with sockets and also you can learn how to make a server that would accept multiple connections at a time. This tutorial explains you always need to start the server first, which is only logical. You should use threads to manage connections and then close them so that you use resources efficiently